# Bootstrap 4 card-footer does not align to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootsrap 4 cards' class 'card-footer', but the footer is not aligning to the bottom of the page.

Here is the link [to the js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37g8yufn/8/)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="card text-center">
     <div class="card-header">Featured</div>
     <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
       <p class="card-text">This text should be equi-distance from header 
       and footer. </p>
       <p class="card-text">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam 
       sapien sem, ornare ac, nonummy non, lobortis a enim. Nam sed 
       tellus id magna elementum tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi 
       tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
       Aliquam ornare wisi eu metus. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. 
       Nam quis nulla. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. 
       </p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    This footer should be at the bottom
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `foot` in card does not mean to stick to bottom of page it is to be in bottom of card

Comment: Yes it does, couldn't think of any way to do that

Answer (score 7):

The card needs to be full height. Bootstrap 4 has a `h-100` class for `height:100%`...

```
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="card h-100 text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    This footer should be at the bottom
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eqfxk9wo/

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also, how would I make sure that everything thing in the card body is center aligned wrt header and footer

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way I think is to give the card-footer a class of mt-auto

```
  <div class="card-footer mt-auto" >
    Whatever
  </div>
```

Comment: solved it for me, in a card-deck with bootstrap v4.6

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, would make my own footer from scratch, but one way which you can use to align this one to the bottom is to add the following to the CSS:

```
.card {
    height: 100vh;
}
```